# Control PCF8574 to output to energise relay in Arduino Iot Cloud

Tags: led

I have been really stuck with this issue for a few weeks now. Hopefully someone here can help me!

I’m currently using an Arduino Nano 33 Iot on Arduino Cloud IoT. Due to the complexity of my project, I would require more output pins and hence, got a PCF8574 extension board to get more pins. I’m using a switch as a control of the output in “Things” on Arduino Iot Cloud. When the switch is turned on, the variable “LED” will be true, and I want the PCF8574 to turn on the relay and when the switched is off, “LED” variable becomes false, thus turning off the relay.

I could achieve this with the GPIO pins from Arduino Nano 33 IoT itself, but from the PCF8574 I’m unable to achieve it. I’m thinking its due to the sinking of the current from the LED into my PCF8574 because my LED turns on without me turning on the relay, but how do I prevent this and still make it work like how I wanted it to?

[image: Circuit Connection]

```
    Sketch generated by the Arduino IoT Cloud Thing "Shorting wires"
  https://create.arduino.cc/cloud/things/117eb328-8ff3-4e25-a895-7c41783028ee

  Arduino IoT Cloud Variables description

  The following variables are automatically generated and updated when changes are made to the Thing

  bool lED;
  bool lED2;
  
  Variables which are marked as READ/WRITE in the Cloud Thing will also have functions
  which are called when their values are changed from the Dashboard.
  These functions are generated with the Thing and added at the end of this sketch.
*/

#include "thingProperties.h"
#include <Wire.h>
#include "PCF8574.h"
#include "Arduino.h"
PCF8574 pcf8574(0x20);

void setup() {
  // Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
  Wire.begin();

  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);

  pcf8574.pinMode(P0, OUTPUT);

  //Wire.begin();
  //Wire.beginTransmission(0x20);
  //Wire.write(0xFF);       // Set all pins as inputs initially
  //Wire.endTransmission();

  delay(1500);  //This delay gives the chance to wait for a Serial Monitor without blocking if none is found
  // Defined in thingProperties.h
  initProperties();

  // Connect to Arduino IoT Cloud
  ArduinoCloud.begin(ArduinoIoTPreferredConnection);

  setDebugMessageLevel(2);
  ArduinoCloud.printDebugInfo();

} 

void loop() {
  ArduinoCloud.update();
}

void onLEDChange()  {
  if (lED) {
    pcf8574.digitalWrite(P0, LOW);
    delay(500);
  //Wire.beginTransmission(0x20);
  //Wire.write(0xFE);
  //Wire.endTransmission();
 
  //delay(500);
}
  else {
    pcf8574.digitalWrite(P0, HIGH);
    delay(500);

  //Wire.beginTransmission(0x20);
  //Wire.write(0xFF);
  //Wire.endTransmission();
  //delay(500);
}
}

void onLED2Change()  {
  if (lED2) {
    digitalWrite(6, HIGH); //Pin 6 of arduino turns on relay
  } else {
    digitalWrite(6, LOW); //Pin 6 of arduino turns off relay
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [PCF8574 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/pcf8574.pdf) contains:

> At power on, the I/Os are high. In this mode, only a current source to VCC is active.

Where the PCF8574 pulls an output high using a an internal 100 uA current source.

The issue is the power-on default of the PCF8574 having high outputs which then turns on your relay and LED, before the software in the Arduino Nano 33 has a chance to initialise the PCF8574 outputs.

> but how do I prevent this and still make it work like how I wanted it to?

Can you rearrange the IOs so that:

1. The relay/LED is connected directly to the Arduino Nano 33
2. Use the PCF8574 for other IOs (which are **not** affected by a power up high state)

**Edit**

Option 3 is to invert the output between the PCF8574 and relay / LED, so that a low output from the PCF8574 is used to turn on the relay / LED. E.g. with:

[image: schematic]

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply! That might explain why the pins of my PCF8574 is always high, however, my PCF8574 could never turn on the relay upon initialising and only the LED lights up faintly.

Comment: 1. I connect my relay directly to the Arduino Nano 33, however I will run into the issue of insufficient GPIO pins, and would have to get more GPIO pins.                                                2. Currently, I do not have any other components that require a power up high state.

Comment: @ArduinoRookie OK, have now added option 3.

Comment: Hello, on my thank you very much! I will definitely give it a try! How large or small should my R2 resistor be?

Answer (score 0):

That PCF8574 has *much* better pull-down than pull-up on its 8 I/O pins, so using a NPN transistor as the relay switch is rather difficult. However, since the PCF8574 is powered from a +3.3V DC supply, while the relay is powered from a +5V supply; a more complex alternative using PNP+NPN driver can work.

GPIO I/O pins are described as pseudo-bidirectional: they pull up weakly, and pull down strongly. This pull-up current can range between 30uA to 300uA and *shouldn't* activate the relay: a logic high should keep the relay off.
The only way to activate the relay is when a PCF8574 output pin is driven low when an I/O pulls strongly to GND (Vss).

The circuit below requires the I/O pin to be set to logic **LOW** to activate the relay. Its advantage is that a logic high turns **OFF** the relay, and a sleeping or idling PC8574 also keeps the relay **OFF**.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCbPaH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Notice that GND must include the 5V supply (for relay), the 3.3V supply of PCF8574, along with the I2C master's GND (Vss).

Comment: Hello! Thank you very much for the explanation and the diagram! So for my PCF8574 code, I should keep it LOW which is 0V to activate the relay. I realised the problem i encounted during the code was I could set the PCF to be high or low at the initial void setup part. However, once it enters the if-else conditions, i could never get it to go LOW or HIGH when i want it to.